# Only keep rows in SQL where the value in columnA is bigger than the value in columnA and the value in columnB is equal to x without a nested question

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

my database:

```
+----------+-------------------+--------+--------+------+
| pk_parts | name              | color  | weight | qoh  |
+----------+-------------------+--------+--------+------+
|        1 | central processor | pink   |     10 |    1 |
|        2 | memory            | gray   |     20 |   32 |
|        3 | disk drive        | black  |    685 |    2 |
|        4 | tape drive        | black  |    450 |    4 |
|        5 | tapes             | gray   |      1 |  250 |
|        6 | line printer      | yellow |    578 |    3 |
|        7 | l-p paper         | white  |     15 |   95 |
|        8 | terminals         | blue   |     19 |   15 |
|        9 | terminal paper    | white  |      2 |  350 |
|       10 | byte-soap         | clear  |      0 |  143 |
|       11 | card reader       | gray   |    327 |    0 |
|       12 | card punch        | gray   |    427 |    0 |
|       13 | paper tape reader | black  |    107 |    0 |
|       14 | paper tape punch  | black  |    147 |    0 |
+----------+-------------------+--------+--------+------+
```

i need to get the name + color of the rows that have a higher weight than card reader and i cant use a nested question.

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: What is a "nested question"?  If you can't use such a thing, can you write a query that does use this?

Comment: This looks like an assignment, and your teacher is probably trying to have you  use a JOIN syntax

Comment: nested question is pretty much a question in a question. I did solve it like this:
SELECT name, color FROM parts WHERE weight>(SELECT weight FROM parts WHERE name='card reader');

but im not allowed to use a question in a question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM parts t1
JOIN parts t2 ON t1.weight > t2.weight 
WHERE t2.name='card reader';
```